# How do I manually interpolate a template in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

I need to inject instances of a custom html-component dynamically, and it would be really useful to be able to "$digest" a template on the fly. How can I do this in angular2? Right now I have this:

```
let html = `<custom-element>Content</custom-element>`;
let template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = html;
document.getElementById('app')
    .appendChild(template.content.firstChild)
```

But this just inserts a plain 'ol element.

http://puu.sh/nKBz8/89825fbb78.png

Here is a plunker showing the way I am trying to do it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JqLWpD?p=preview

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2