# How to get Angular2 to bind component in innerHTML

Tags: angular

I want to create a component `myApp` that will embed HTML from a property on the controller in its template.  However, some of that HTML may include other component selectors.

```
import {InfoComponent} from ...
@Component({
    selector: 'myApp',
    template: `<div [innerHTML]='hData'></div>
               <myInfo></myInfo>`,
    directives: [InfoComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
   hData = "<myInfo></myInfo>";
}

@Component({
   selector: 'myInfo',
   template: "<b>This is a test</b>"
})
export class InfoComponent {
}
```

In this example, I would expect to see `This is a test` displayed twice.  However, it doesn't appear that the Angular2 engine picks up on the fact that the selector of the Component has been injected so the template never gets generated for the `<myInfo></myInfo>` selector that is add via the binding.

You can see a [demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jHLIYM4HHrOBBvQmPjL2?p=preview).

Is there a way to get Angular2 to parse the selector in the same way it does with the selector that is added explicitly in the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to make `[innerHtml]="..."` instantiate Angular components or directives or establish any bindings.

The closest for this requirement is <strike>[DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html).</strike> (DynamicComponentLoader was removed a while ago) `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`

See [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) for an example

Since RC.5 Angular2 sanitizes styles and HTML added through binding.
See [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868) for more details.

Comment: I think the DynamicComponentLoader is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks so much.

Comment: But if it's not a component you're trying to load how does it work? If it's only a simple html string?

Comment: Then wrap it in a component. If this isn't possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2 might be helpful

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've been trying to implement the DynamicComponentLoader per your suggestion but ran into an issue where one of the loaded components requires a service.  I've posted about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490509/how-to-inject-a-service-into-a-dynamic-component-with-angular2.  Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: DynamicComponentLoader link is dead.

Comment: Please, any working example with the last release? Thank you.

Comment: I guess you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868

Comment: I added a bit to my answer that is probably what you run into.

Comment: Thank you Günter, I will check :)