# Ionic2 html tags not displayed in i18n string with inner html

Tags: html, angular, ionic2, angular2-directives

My issue is related to the app internazionalization in Ionic2 and Angular2. I've successfully rendered a message after some investigation which includes native html tags nevertheless when I try to include ionic tags, they are not rendered.

I have an i18n file in `/src/assets/i18n/en.json` with this message:

```
"tutorial.desc" : "<p>Open the left-side menu <ion-icon ios='ios-menu' md='md-menu' style='font-size: 1.1em;'></ion-icon></p><p> Tap on <strong>My places</strong> and add yours.</p>"
```

The native html tags are displayed as expected but ion-icon tag is missing.

This is the html source:

```
<div [innerHTML]="'tutorial.desc' | translate"></div>
```

This is the outputed html:

```
<div ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l="<p>Open the left-side menu </p><p> Tap on <strong>My places</strong> and add yours.</p>">
    <p>Open the left-side menu </p>
    <p> Tap on <strong>My places</strong> and add yours.</p>
</div>
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: ion-icon is a custom component in ionic framework.. not really a basic html element..

Comment: @suraj I know. So what can I do?

Comment: you will have to do it without `innerHtml` i guess

Comment: You can check this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408605/how-to-get-angular2-to-bind-component-in-innerhtml