# Angular 2 : How to dynamically load component control inside another component from code

Tags: angularjs

I need a help . How to render   from typescript

looking for help using @angular/core.

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'childcomp',
  template: 
    `<div>{{html}}</div>`

})
export class ChildComponent
{
  html:string =
  "

## Child Component

";
parentAttribID :string =25 ;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'anotherchildcomp',
  template: 
    `<h1>Another Child Component</h1>`

})
export class AnotherChildComponent
{
    @Input attribID: string ;

}

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/eEu1W4xzQvQ3dtlUbs7b?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408605/how-to-get-angular2-to-bind-component-in-innerhtml/43885672#43885672

Comment: same issue posted by some one

Answer (score 0):

Go throug the example

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 Nested Components</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Injecting child components

```
const {Component} = ng.core;
const {bootstrap} = ng.platform.browser;


@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    styles : [`
        .child {
            background : #aaa;
            padding: 10px;
            overflow:auto;
        }
        .book{
            background : #0a0; 
            padding:20px;
            margin:10px;
            width:300px;
            float:left;
        }
    `],
    template: `
        <div class="child">
            <h2>Books :</h2>
            <div class="book" *ngFor="#book of books">
   <h4> Title : {{book.title}} </h4> <h4>Price: {{book.price}}</h4> 
  </div>
        </div>
    `
})
class ChildComponent {
    books = [
        {
            title : 'Love Story',
            price : 'Rs. 1400'
        },
        {
            title : 'Two States',
            price : 'Rs. 1700'
        },
        {
            title : 'Computer fundamentals',
            price : 'Rs. 1000'
        }
    ]
}


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles : [`
        .parent {
            background : #c7c7c7;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    `],
    template: `
        <div class="parent">
            <h1>Author : {{name}}</h1>
            <child-component></child-component>
        </div>
    `,
    directives : [ChildComponent]
})
class AppComponent {
    name = "John Doe"
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, []);
```

Comment: My requirement is different, where is the innerComponent.

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html

Can you look in to this link.