# Custom user template for a component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got a component that has it's default template:

```js
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-component',
        template: `
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                    <div *ngIf="contentRef.childNodes.length == 0">DEFAULT: <b>{{contentData}}</b></div>
                    <div #contentRef><ng-content select=".content"></ng-content></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `
    })
    export class MyComponent {
        contentData = "DATA";
    }
```

I would like a user to be able to specify his own templates for some parts of the component when using it. So it can be written as follows:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
    import {MyComponent} from './my.component';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        directives: [MyComponent],
        template: `
            <my-component></my-component> 
            <br/>
            <my-component>
                <div class="content">
                    CUSTOM: <i>{{contentData}}</i>
                </div>
            </my-component>
        `
    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

It produces the following markup:

```html
<my-app>
        <my-component>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <!--template bindings={}--><div>DEFAULT: <b>DATA</b></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </my-component> 
        <br>
        <my-component>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <!--template bindings={}-->
                <div><div class="content">
                CUSTOM: <i></i>
            </div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </my-component>
    </my-app>
```

So the component's 'contentData' property is not rendered within the custom template. Is it possible to provide the custom template with a specific binding context somehow? Or is there a better way to implement the case with a custom user template?

Answer (score 0):

[How to realize website with hundreds of pages in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2) shows an approach.

This is no official solution and to me it currently looks like this is likely to break before the final release.
Angular2 has a strong tendency to statically building and resolving the bindings.

Either you can work with [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) or you don't build on Angulars binding features for dynamically added content.