# How to render text/html response ,using angular2 js

Tags: typescript, angular, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

```
 @Component({
     selector: 'app-data',
     template: <div><input type="button" (click)="getData();" value="GET DATA"/>    </div> <div id="child">{{data}}</div>
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please format the code properly. This is unreadable.

Comment: I guess you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Angular 2 innerHTML binding:

```
<div [innerHTML]="yourHtmlContentVariable"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Sjors, i have to try with http request and render html response that content js or css so how can be do that on button click

Comment: If I understand your question correct: you can create a variable for the innerHTML binding, which will be an empty string on init. When your http request has finished, assign the response to that variable

Comment: Alright! Can you mark the answer as the solution to your problem?