# What is the best way to detect focus event in @contentChild in angular2?

Tags: angular

Assumed I have a projected native input between ng-content tag.
I know, I can get the reference to the projected input with @ContentChild.
I wonder how I could detect e.g. the focus event of the projected input element in the parent component?

Comment: I deleted my answer again, sorry but i thought you work with two components. got your question wrong there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way. The [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) event doesn't bubble, therefore needs to be listened to on the element directly.

If you can get the reference using `@ContentChild()` you can use

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {}

someMethod() {
  this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
    this.focusableChild.nativeElement, 
    'addEventListener', ['focus', onFocus.bind(this)]
  ); 
}
```

If you control how your component is used you could apply a directive to your content like explained in [How to realize website with hundreds of pages in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2) that forwards `focus` events to bubbling events by dispatching a custom event the parent element can listen to like

```
@Component({
  template: `... <ng-content></ng-content>
  ...
})
class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('custom-focus', ['$event'])
  onFocus(event) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx, Günter. It looks like an acceptable way. Would you suggest this, or wouldn´t you build components in that way (content projection of simple elements?)

Comment: I would need to know more about your requirements but in general there is no strong reason why you shouldn't do that. Using the `Renderer` instead of direct access to `focusableChild.nativeElement.xxx` keeps it within the bounds of proper Angular2 way of doing stuff.