# How do I listen to a ContentChild event without hooking up via template?

Tags: angular

I need to listen for an event from an array of tab components. These tabs emit "onMinimized" however I would rather hook up to these events in one line of code than entering `(onMinimized)="hide"` for each tab component entry in the template. There is an array of ContentChildren that I have which I can loop through.

I want to do something similar to has follows in the parent:

```
@ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;

...

ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.tabs.map((t: TabComponent) => {
    t.addEventListener("onMinimized", this.hide);
  });
}

hide() {
  // hide tabs
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Is onMinimized is a custom event emitter? cuz then you can subscribe to it in code.  a question though - since tabs is an array, aren't you looping through that array to create the TabComponents?  or are you creating the tabs a different way?

Comment: Each tab is defined in the template (though they could be in an array I suppose). How do I create an event listener to an angular "output" of a ContentChild via a ContentChild reference?

Comment: Found this, but its not exactly what I'm looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746058/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-focus-event-in-contentchild-in-angular2

Comment: can you post the component code for one of your tabs?

Answer (score 12):

Figured it out after some trial and error.

```
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.tabs.map((t: TabComponent) => {
      t.minimizeTab.subscribe(() => { this.hide(); })
    });
  }
```

The way to approach the problem was to consider that the component had a property which was an EventEmitter (just like all angular Outputs). EventEmitters are observables, so you can simply subscribe to the stream of events.