# How to build plugins style web platform with angular2

Tags: plugins, angular

The idea is not new, like Wordpress, Oxwall : a platform created by some guru guy that allowing other dev guys to add new apps (like forum, blog, market-place, whatever) into the platform easily. By easy, we mean either just install new plugin by upload or less user friendly coding new plugin without changing the core code.

Actually, we have a working solution with angular1 but quite clumsy, that's it, multiple stand-alone ng-app within a website, like:

- domain.com/forum-spa
- domain.com/dating-app-spa
- ..etc..

Good thing about it is quite straightforward to implement, not much to worry about lazy-loading. But we are not happy with that approach for many reasons.

Angular2 is really close. We hope it can bring a better solution for building a large web platform

Comment: What are the many reasons so people can know in advance what approach to suggest or not to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

- iframe
- custom components that are added at build time that are added depending on user data like explained in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)
  This approach is compatible with the offline template compiler
- There is also a more flexible way that supports user-provided component templates [How to realize website with hundreds of pages in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2)
  This approach is **not** compatible with the offline template compiler and requires the Angular parser and compiler to be included in the build output.