# No provider for Platform

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

So I have come across this issue making a unit test for an Angular 4 application

What happens is that it keeps giving the error stated here in the question title.

I tried to google it, tried to import a whole bunch of different modules and finally found that a close answer to what this "Platform" is might be the browserModule from `@angular/browser` Platform.

So in my unit testing, I tried to import it and declare it but it did not help.

Can anyone please help with this as I'm not even sure what this "Platform" is?

Question: what is exactly this "Platform" in the error and how to fix it?

Thanks.

I have attached my code as below:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async} from "@angular/core/testing";
import { DebugElement, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, PlatformRef} from 
"@angular/core";
import { TeamCreationAssignmentComponent } from "./team-creation-assignment.component";
import { OdmService } from "../../services/odm/odm.service";
import { UserNotificationService } from "../../services/user/user-notification.service";
import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material";
import { OVERLAY_PROVIDERS, ScrollStrategyOptions, ScrollDispatcher} from "@angular/cdk/overlay";

describe('Team creation assignment component', () => {
let comp: TeamCreationAssignmentComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TeamCreationAssignmentComponent>;

let odmServiceSub = {};


beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

        declarations: [TeamCreationAssignmentComponent],
        //imports: [BrowserModule],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        providers: [
            {provide: OdmService, useValue: odmServiceSub}, 
            UserNotificationService, 
            MatSnackBar, 
            OVERLAY_PROVIDERS, 
            ScrollStrategyOptions,
            ScrollDispatcher,
        ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TeamCreationAssignmentComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('should have defined component', () => {
    expect(comp).toBeDefined();
})
```

});

Comment: paste your test file in here.

Comment: What is a platform already have answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407604/what-is-angular-platform-browser) and there are more results in Google Search.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification of what "Platform" is. But like I said, I tried browsermodule in my testing code but nothing worked

Comment: If you are using `@angular-cli` generate a component using it `ng g c dummy` then check the spec file generated and compare with yours.

Comment: @sabithpocker I compared the dummy test spec with mine, there is literally not much of a difference except that in my spec ts file, I have  a lot more providers. But I have to declare the providers otherwise it will throw a bunch of errors to me. I resolved a lot of other "no provider for XXX" errors before I came down here to this "No provider for Platform"

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem (in Angular 5) using FocusMonitor and wanting to test the component depending on it.  FocusMonitor in turn has a dependency of Platform.

In your case it's the same dependency with [ScrollDispatcher](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/scrolling/scroll-dispatcher.ts).

You'll need to add Platform in your TestBed's providers

```
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
```

...

```
providers: [
  {provide: OdmService, useValue: odmServiceSub}, 
  UserNotificationService, 
  MatSnackBar, 
  OVERLAY_PROVIDERS, 
  ScrollStrategyOptions,
  ScrollDispatcher,
  Platform
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not part of that project anymore. Let me pass it to my teammate and see if this works. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Confirmed that this works. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get a message that there is "No provider for XXX" it generally means that you are missing something from the `providers` array in the `configureTestingModule` method. Have you tried adding `PlatformRef` to the `providers` array? Like this:

```
providers: [
    {provide: OdmService, useValue: odmServiceSub}, 
    UserNotificationService, 
    MatSnackBar, 
    OVERLAY_PROVIDERS, 
    ScrollStrategyOptions,
    ScrollDispatcher,
    PlatformRef // <- added here
],
```

One thing you are missing however is a call to `detectChanges` in your second `beforeEach`, it should look like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TeamCreationAssignmentComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges(); // <- this is required
});
```

One thing I will say is that in my Angular 4 app, there are around 800 unit tests, and not a single one of them uses or requires this `PlatformRef`. I think the issue is the missing `detectChanges` rather than anything to do with this "platform".

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that I used angular material throughout the application, don't know if that could be the cause. But I'll try your suggestion once I get a chance and let you know. Thanks