# What's the difference between BrowserModule and platformBrowserDynamic?

Tags: angular

What are the purposes of these two modules?

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['angular2/platform/browser' vs. '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993476/angular2-platform-browser-vs-angular-platform-browser-dynamic)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`platformBrowserDynamic` is a function used to bootstrap an Angular application.

`CommonModule` is a module that provides all kinds of services and directives one usually wants to use in an Angular2 application like `ngIf`. `CommonModule` is platform-independent.

`BrowserModule` exports `CommonModule` and provides a few services specific to the browser platform (in contrary to `ServerModule` or `ServiceWorkerModule`).

`BrowserModule` should only be imported in `AppModule`, `CommonModule` can be imported everywhere.

Comment: I think ngIf is from CommonModule, BrowserModule just re-exports it. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-browser-vs-common-module

Comment: Second @maxisam. The main purpose of BrowserModule is different than what presented in this answer. [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/frequent-ngmodules) makes it clear: "For apps that run in the browser, import BrowserModule in the root AppModule because **it provides services that are essential to launch and run a browser app**." and "BrowserModule imports CommonModule, which contributes many common directives such as ngIf and ngFor. **Additionally, BrowserModule re-exports CommonModule** making all of its directives available to any module that imports BrowserModule."

Comment: Yes, he is right. It wasn't so easy to find out back then when I answered. There were no docs ;-) I updated my answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Fair point. It was a dark age and you shed some light at that time :)

Answer (score 8):

**Angular Modules** help organize an application into cohesive blocks of functionality.

Root module needs to import the `BrowserModule` from `@angular/platform-browser` to the imports array.

**BrowserModule** registers critical application service providers. It also includes common directives like `NgIf` and `NgFor` which become immediately visible and usable in any of this modules component templates.

QuickStart application is a web application that runs in a browser which involves this Browser Module

**PlatformBrowserDynamic** - contains the client side code that processes templates

See these links, this might help also: [@angular/platform-browser vs. @angular/platform-browser-dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993476/angular2-platform-browser-vs-angular-platform-browser-dynamic)

and

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: I don't think they are the same question.

Comment: @Kevin The linked question is asking ***exactly*** the same thing as this question is.

Answer (score 2):

BrowserModule-Exports required infrastructure for all Angular apps. Included by default in all Angular apps created with the CLI new command. Re-exports CommonModule and ApplicationModule, making their exports and providers available to all apps.

platformBrowserDynami-to bootstrap an application.