# Projection Manipulation with Dynamic Compiling

Tags: typescript, angular

How can I get access to the projected html as a precompiled html string, prevent Angular from compiling it, modify it, and then recompile it in a desired location? This is all pretty easy with Angular 1 and I'm trying to convert my directives over to angular 2 but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way (not too sure though).

What you can do instead is creating components with templates from strings like shown in [How to realize website with hundreds of pages in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2)