# Dynamically create component passing template

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

I have a service which dynamically creates components, (dialogs in my example) -

```
  createDialog(component: Type, providers: any = []) {
    this._resolver.resolveComponent(component).then(factory => {
      let resolved = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(providers);
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolved, this._container.injector);
        this._container.createComponent(factory, null, injector, []);        
    });
  }
```

But the problem is that right now I need to create a template for each component with `md-dialog` element in it and pass needed dom elements inside `ng-content`, like this -

```
  <md-dialog [displayActions]="false" class="warning">
    <div content>
      <h4> Warning
        <a href="close" (click)="close($event)"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
      </h4>
      <div>
        Some content
      </div>
      <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button save" (click)="continue()">
        Continue
      </button>
    </div>
  </md-dialog>
```

But what I want to, is to pass an object with template to createDialog function, and create component with this template, for example like this -

```
  class DialogTemplate {
    header: string;
    content: string;
    actions: string;
  }
  createDialog(component: Type, providers: any = [], template: DialogTemplate) {
    /*Some imaginary code*/
    component.template = `
      <md-dialog [displayActions]="false" class="warning">
        <div content>
        </div>
      </md-dialog>`;
    /*Imaginary code end*/
    this._resolver.resolveComponent(component).then(factory => {
      let resolved = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(providers);
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolved, this._container.injector);
        this._container.createComponent(factory, null, injector, []);        
    });
  }
```

Is it possible to do it this way, or something similar? If it is, could someone please link me to an API which allows to do it or give an example?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2 `DynamicComponentLoader` was deprecated in favor of `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` but otherwise this should still work.

Comment: Thanks for link, I'll give it a try...