# Angular 2 template can't get event binding

Tags: typescript, angular

I try to create my own structure directive that can create some DOM structure (button group in my case). I want to create custom tags for wrapper and child and apply custom classes.

I stuck on moment - Output event. I finished directive. It's working. (I make DOM manipulation inside this directive).
But now I can't emit event from this directive 9I found answers that it's because events should be static.   like  - `(click)="some()")`
But how I can do it if my child's created dynamically? (For now I use `AddEventListener`).

and have this error: **Event binding onBtnClick not emitted by any directive on an embedded template**

Thanks for any information.

Here is my component code:

```
import {Component, Injectable, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

import { BtnGroupChildStructure } from './button_group.directive';
import { Config } from 'appConfig';
/* ------- !Config  ---------*/

const MODULE_NAME: string = 'button_group';
const MODULE_PATH: string = `${Config.getProdFolderName()}/shared/components/${MODULE_NAME}`;

@Component({
    selector : 'cgm_button_group',
    template : `<template *btnGroupChildStruct="config" 
                (onBtnClick)="t_handleBtnClick($event)"></template>`,
    host : {'class': 'button-group-box'},
    directives : [
        BtnGroupChildStructure
    ]
})
@Injectable()
export class ButtonGroupComponent implements OnInit {

    private _config: Object;

    @Input() config(val: Object) {
        console.log(val);
        Object.assign(this._config, val);
        console.log(this._config);
    }

    @Output onBtnClick = new EventEmitter<string>();

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    private t_handleBtnClick(buttonName: string): void {
        this.onBtnClick.emit(buttonName);
    }
}
```

Here is Directive code

```
import { Directive, Input, 
    ViewContainerRef, ElementRef, TemplateRef, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({ selector : '[btnGroupChildStruct]'})
export class BtnGroupChildStructure implements OnInit {

    private _hostEl;
    private _config: Object = {};

    @Input() set btnGroupChildStruct(val: Object) {
        console.log(val);
        Object.assign(this._config, val);
    }

    @Output() onBtnClick = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(
        private _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private _elementRef: ElementRef
    ) {
        this._hostEl = this._elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement;

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //console.log(this._templateRef);
        this._generateChilds();
        this._hostEl.appendChild(this._generateGroup());
        //this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef);
    }

    /**
     * _generateChilds -> generate childs structure
     * @returns {DocumentFragment}
     * @private
     */
    private _generateChilds(): DocumentFragment {
        let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

        if (this._config.hasOwnProperty('buttonNamesList')) {
            this._config.buttonNamesList.forEach((buttonName) => {
                let item = document.createElement(this._config.tagChild);
                this._addClasses(item, this._config.childClasses);
                item.textContent = buttonName;
                this._addClickHandler(item);
                fragment.appendChild(item);
            })
        } else {
            throw new Error('Button group Directive. _generateChilds. Can"t get _config buttonNamesList prop');
        }

        return fragment;

    }

    /**
     * _generateGroup -> generate button group
     * @returns {HTMLElement}
     * @private
     */
    private _generateGroup(): HTMLElement {
        let wrapperTag;
        if (this._config.hasOwnProperty('tagWrapper')) {
            wrapperTag = document.createElement(this._config.tagWrapper);
            this._addClasses(wrapperTag, this._config.wrapperClasses);
            wrapperTag.appendChild(this._generateChilds());
        } else {
            throw new Error('Button group Directive. _generateGroup. Can"t get _config tagWrapper prop');
        }

        return wrapperTag;
    }

    /**
     * _addClasses -> Add classes to el
     * @param el (HTMLElement) -> handled Element
     * @param classesStr (String) -> string of classes
     * @private
     */
    private _addClasses(el: HTMLElement, classesStr: string): void {
        if (!el || !classesStr) throw new Error('_addClasses. Missed one of parameter');
        el.className = classesStr
    }

    private _addClickHandler(el: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!el) throw new Error('_addClickHandler. Non exist element');
        el.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
            this.onBtnClick.emit(el.textContent);
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: `@Output` needs to be `@Output()`

Comment: Hi Gunter. Correct. I fix it but got the same error.

Comment: If you use a structural directive on a `<template>` tag, don't add the `*` prefix. This is only for implicit use of the `<template>` tag. I don't know how to listen to events from structural directives but try it without the `*` and please report if it changes anything. Maybe try if the structural directives does anything without events at all first. If you remove the `*` you need to use `[btnGroupChildStruct]="..."` otherwise the string `"config"` will be assigned instead of the value of `@Input() config`.

Comment: Hi Gunter again. When I try to use some 'real' tag (section- for example) instead template tag, tt's not works because my dynamically created elements is not render inside this tag. So that's why I used template. Because I don't know how I can place dynamically created elements inside this tag. I tried to use this _//this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef);_  but I don't know How I can create reference to my dynamic elements.

Comment: An example with Plunker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: Thanks Gunter so much for your help.

Comment: Looks like it's dynamic component builder stuff, but I just want to create few element dynamically and insert in correctly inside my component by ng2 way (I don;t want to use  _append_ or innerHTML). Is it possible?  (like with _this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView_)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you actually try to accomplish? Have you tried to use `<template btnGroupChildStruct="config" ...` (without `*`) as suggested above?

Comment: actually I tried to use some component where I create dynamically set of html elements. And after that I want to append this elements inside my host element with all angular rules (I want to bind some event handling or expressions. But I don't know how it can be applied to dynamic elements)

From start I use *template* tag because this tag is like _non-real_ and all dynamic childs can be easy append inside. But I have issue with ng2 bindings event. When I switch to "real" tag _div_  I don't know how I can apped my elements inside this tag with all ng2 rules.

Comment: I saw that I can paste some html structure inside host  with _this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef)_  

Lets imagine that I have few dynamically created elements. How I can paste it inside  my component host tag an how i can apply all angular features (event handling/expressions etc).

Comment: Angular2 doesn't process bindings of dynamically added HTML. Everything, also the `<template>` element and its content needs to be statically in a template for bindings to work or for components and directives with matching selectors to be instantiated. A workaround or hack that really makes it possible with dynamically generated HTML is shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2

Comment: Thanks so much Gunter!