# Angular 2 Adding more html codes for imported component

Tags: angular

i m pretty new in angular2 and i have a question.
Is there a way to add more content in a component.ts that was imported from an external file ?

I have a page-header.component in multiple pages that are all the same except i change some titles like this.

```
<page-header [headerLinks]="['link1', 'link2', 'link3']"></page-header>
```

page-header.component.html looks like this:

```
<div class="page-header-links">
<a *ngFor="let headerLink of headerLinks" href="#">{{ headerLink }}</a>
</div>
```

I would like to expand the page-header-component in my next files and only in this next file. something like this:

```
<div class="page-header-links">
<a *ngFor="let headerLink of headerLinks" href="#">{{ headerLink }}</a>
</div>

add more content ---
<span class="rectangle-shape"></span>
<h3> title </h3>
<span class="rectangle-shape"></span>
and more
```

any idea how can i do this?

i tried this but maybe i miss doing something in ts file ?!

```
 <page-header [headerLinks]="['link1', 'link2', 'link3']">

 <span class="rectangle-shape"></span>
 <h3> title </h3>
 <span class="rectangle-shape"></span>

 </page-header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do right:

```
<page-header [headerLinks]="['link1', 'link2', 'link3']">
  <span class="rectangle-shape"></span>
  <h3> title </h3>
  <span class="rectangle-shape"></span>
</page-header>
```

You just need to add `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside page-header.component.html, like this:

```
<div class="page-header-links">
  <a *ngFor="let headerLink of headerLinks" href="#">{{ headerLink }}</a>
</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<div [innerHTML]="somePropertyWithHTML">
```

but that only adds plain HTML and doesn't resolve any bindings or instantiate Angular2 components or directives for the added HTML.

If you need this see Maybe [How to realize website with hundreds of pages in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2)