# In Angular 2, is there a way to do Angular binding in a string

Tags: typescript, angular

If I build an HTML template using routing, like here

```
<ul class="sb-sub-menu">
    <li>
        <a [routerLink]="['clientadd']">Client Add</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This works as I would expect.

However, if I was building a dynamic UI from a HTML formatted string, the routing doesn't seem to apply.

```
<ul class="sb-sub-menu" [innerHTML]="links"></ul>
```

where

```
links: string = `
<li>
   <a [routerLink]="['clientadd']">Client Add</a>
</li>`
```

In my situation, the list of links is more complicated and I wanted to see if there was a way to load them as templated HTML, instead of needing to create a model.

Is there such a way to load a templated HTML string and have routing working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't process dynamically added HTML in any way. No bindings, no directive or component instantiation, ... except sanitization for security purposes.

You can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` to dynamically add components like explained in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

If you really need dynamic HTML (for example user-provided) you can use the approach explained in [How to realize website with hundreds of pages in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create links dynamically using `*ngFor` instead of using `innerHtml`

For e.g.

```
<ul class="sb-sub-menu">
  <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
    <a [routerLink]="[item.url]">{{item.label}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what we ended up doing.