# update the text returned with templateUrl using reflect.getMetadata angular2 rc4

Tags: typescript, angular

In my component I return the template code using Reflect

```
this.http.get(Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', TemplateComponent)[0].templateUrl)
    .map((res:Response) => res.text())
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log( data);
        },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
);
```

then I add Dynamically a component and I call this http.get method to return  the template text after adding a component dynamically

```
resolver.resolveComponent(component).then((factory) => {
    componentRef = target.createComponent(factory);
}); // this method permit to add a component dynamically
```

so I need to get the template code with updating component

Comment: I guess this would be a better approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2

Comment: this is about an old version of angular2 !!

Comment: What is "this". The proposed solution in the linked question should still work (maybe with minor adjustments).

Comment: Yes it works except that I want to update the source code of template
When I add a component A within the component B I want to show the template of B with a source Code of Component A

Comment: That's all I can offer. Maybe someone else.