# angular2 embed template to index.html

Tags: templates, angular, browser-cache

Is it a way to use similar functionality like angular 1 has to embed template in index.html file:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="app/klasses/klass-detail/klass-detail.component.html">
  your template here
</script>
```

The reason that I am asking for it is problem of caching static files (*.html) by browser and potential update to template could not be pick up if browser has not caching off - I can not depend on it - also would limit numbers of requests....

Comment: Angular2's `@Component`s have the `templateUrl` attribute. Have you seen it?

Comment: Or inlIne template using 'template' attribute

Comment: Yes I know about templateUrl and in-line templates - questions is about embedding template in script tags...

Comment: Angular doesn't provide support for templates in script tags. You can use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2 to create components dynamically where you pass the template as string but it's a hack.