# Angular2 library size

Tags: angularjs, angular, frameworks

I have watched the latest `ng-conf` and saw Brad Green says Angular2 now weight 45K, and angular1 is 56K. I try to understand what those number represent, but without success.

I also saw [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Restuta/cda69e50a853aa64912d) that list Angular1 and 2 frameworks by size. And there are completely different numbers there.

The [ng-conf YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAjjI35RcUE) (it's in 57:10).

The relevant slide:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand well your question ;-) In fact, it's after packaging your application and using tree shaking. The latter is a technique that leverages modules to only keep what is used in the application (apply to third party libraries as well).

I think these two links could help you:

- http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/
- https://medium.com/@Rich_Harris/tree-shaking-versus-dead-code-elimination-d3765df85c80#.6s0vcyv49

Answer (score 0):

The presentation was about offline template compiler that is currently experimental, that eliminates loading Angular2 parser and compiler into the browser by processing the templates and converting all declarative bindings to JS at compile time. 
This allows to reduce the Angular2 package code size that actually needs to be loaded into the browser.

If one requires solutions like demonstrated in [How to realize website with hundreds of pages in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008476/how-to-realize-website-with-hundreds-of-pages-in-angular2) the parser and compiler would be required to be loaded into the browser and lose this size benefit.